# Do Javascript Numbers get represented as 64bit numbers in a 32bit browser?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm a bit confused about the size of a javascript number in a 32bit browser. Is it still represented as a 64bit number with max value at 2^53?

Comment: It should be platform independent.

Comment: Side note : Number.MAX_VALUE & Number.MIN_VALUE can be used to find the max and min values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A number in Javascript is a [double precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). It's the same regardless of the platform that it runs on.

Answer (score 8):

Answers couldn't be more wrong, it does depend on engine.

In V8 (Google Chrome, Opera, Node.js) 32-bit:

Integers that fit 31-bit signed representation (from -1073741824 to 1073741823) are represented directly by embedding it them in [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer).

Any other number is generally represented as a heap object that has a 64-bit double as a field for the numeric value (think of Java `Double` wrapper). In optimized functions such numbers can be temporarily stored directly on the stack and registers. Also certain kind of arrays can store doubles directly "permanently".

In V8 64-bit:

Same as 32-bit except integers can now fit in 32-bit signed representation (from -2147483648 to 2147483647) instead of 31-bit.

Comment: Yes I noticed something along these lines in Chrome. If you type 1<<30, 1<<31, 1<<32 into the console it sheds some light on how integers are handled. Results are 1073741824, -2147483648, 1. Integers are indeed stored as 32 bit by default it seems. Perhaps they expand to 64 bit when required.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose my answer lies on MDN @ [64-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_data#64-bit_integers)